# How do I learn sensor data from knx group address for c#?

Tags: c#, .net, knx

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var connection = new KnxConnectionRouting();

            connection.Connect();
            connection.KnxEventDelegate += Event;
            connection.Action("1/0/1", false);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }

        static void Event(string address, string state)
        {
            var connection = new KnxConnectionRouting();

            if (address == "1/0/1")
            {
                decimal temp = (decimal)connection.FromDataPoint("1.001", state);
                Console.WriteLine("New Event: device " + address + " has status " + temp);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("New Event: device " + address + " has status " + state);
        }
```

"state" variable returning from "Event" method returns null.temp value always gives zero result.

Any suggestion ?

I used [KNXLib](https://github.com/lifeemotions/knx.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what datapoint type does your group address 1/0/1 actually have?

If it is supposed to be a sensor value, probably 9.001, or? I this case, change `connection.FromDataPoint("1.001", state)` to `connection.FromDataPoint("9.001", state)`.

But then sending a boolean value to the same group address (`connection.Action("1/0/1", false)`) makes no sense.